# Oracle sql - sorting record with selected records on top

Tags: sql, oracle

If you have a table that has data like this:

```
USER_ID          USERNAME
  34267             mark
  15669             john
  61268             allan
  87779             mary
```

You want select these data and to sort them were user id with the lowest value should be on top of list. Then after that, all the rest of the records will be sorted alphabetically by username. So this case John should be first then followed allan, mark then mary.

How can you do this WITHOUT using UNION. This is only part of a much complex query which I have where there are multiple ordering for each column. so, I cant really use union for this. They are the 5th and 6th column order priority where this logic should be applied.

Oracle db version is 12c

Comment: `ORDER BY USER_ID DESC, USERNAME`??

Comment: in this case order by USERNAME is never used because USER_ID is probably unique

Comment: @Jaydipj: he wants only ONE row with the lowest user_id to be first, and then order rest of the rows by username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by`:

```
order by (case when row_number() over (order by user_id) = 1 then 1 else 2 end),   -- put minimum user_id on top
         name asc
```

Comment: will it work too if I already have multiple order by columns listed before it? (e.g. order by col1, col2, col3, col4, (case when row number...... ...etc)

Comment: @HingleMcJingleberry yes

Comment: If you order by `col1, col2` etc. first, and then by user_id, then you *probably* want the lowest `user_id` for each fixed value of `col1, col2` etc. (otherwise the question really makes no sense). If so, then **no**, it will not work as written. You would have to change the analytic clause to `over (partition by col1, col2, ...  order by user_id)`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the third column that could be used to order your records:

```
select USER_ID, USERNAME, case when USER_ID=(select max(USER_ID) from your_table)
                               then 1 else 2 end as firstOrder
from your_table
order by firstOrder asc, USERNAME asc
```

so you will have `john` as first record because his `firstOrder` is `1` and then you will order by `USERNAME`.